# Delete rows (dynamic amount) based on cell's content

Tags: vba, loops, excel, range

Sorry if this is simple, this is my first time trying VBA.

So I want this macro to get rid of rows I don't need, and for every entity it has a total field (about every 20 records or so) and I made this script:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer
LastRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 3 To LastRow
    If Range("C" & i) = "Result" Then
        Rows(i & ":" & i).Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=x1Up
    End If
Next
```

And that worked perfectly! Then I tried to a similar thing.. I tried to go through each row (record) in a data set and then if a certain field does not contain the string "INVOICE" then I don't need that row and I can delete it. So I just added into my current loop (why loop twice?) So now it looks like this:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer
LastRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 3 To LastRow
    If Range("C" & i) = "Result" Then
        Rows(i & ":" & i).Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=x1Up
    End If
    If Not InStr(1, Range("Q" & i), "INVOICE") Then
        Rows(i & ":" & i).Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=x1Up
    End If
Next
```

That second bit as far as I can tell just randomly starts deleting rows with no rhyme or reason. Rows where the Q field doesn't contain invoice sometimes stay sometimes go, and same if it does contain invoice. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Don't loop. Use Autofilter :) See [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s)

Comment: ...or if you're going to loop, then start on the last row and work up (`For i = LastRow to 3 Step -1`) so you won't tread on your loop index when you delete a row (thus shifting up the row below...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are indeed two approaches: `AutoFilter` and `For Loop`. Of the two, `AutoFilter` is much faster especially with large datasets, but it will often need a very good set-up. The `For Loop` is easy, but it has marginal returns, especially when your data start hitting 100k rows or more.

Also, `Not InStr(1, Range("Q" & i), "INVOICE")` might seem like the best way but IMHO it's not. `InStr` returns a number, so it's better if you either do further comparison like `Not InStr(1, Range("Q" & i), "INVOICE") > 0` or just simply `InStr(1, Range("Q" & i), "INVOICE") = 0`. In any case, I used the former in my second code below.

Following are both approaches. They are tested on simple data. The code might seem a bit bulky, but the logic is sound. Refer to the comments as well for other things.

**AutoFilter approach:**

```
Sub RemoveViaFilter()

    Dim WS As Worksheet: Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ModifyMe")
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With WS
        '--For condition "Result"
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row '--Compatible if there are more rows.
        With Range("A2:Q" & LastRow) '--Assuming your header is in Row 2 and records start at Row 3.
            .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Result" '--Field:=3 is Column C if data starts at A
            .Cells.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete '--Delete the visible ones.
        End With
        '--For condition "<>*INVOICE*"
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        With Range("A2:Q" & LastRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="<>*INVOICE*" '--Field:=17 is Column Q if data starts at A
            .Cells.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**For-loop approach:**

```
Sub RemoveViaLoop()

    Dim WS As Worksheet: Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet6")
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = WS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    Dim Iter As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With WS
        For Iter = LastRow To 3 Step -1 '--Move through the rows from bottom to up by 1 step (row) at a time.
            If .Range("C" & Iter) = "Result" Or Not InStr(1, .Range("Q" & Iter).Value, "Invoice") > 0 Then
                .Rows(Iter).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next Iter
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try this out today using auto filter, since my datasets can get bulky and this is running a back machine that I don't want to bog down.

Answer (score 1):

You should `OR` your conditions together so that if either reason exists the line is deleted.  Otherwise since you're deleting lines within a preset range, you'll end up skipping more lines than you are currently.  Currently it looks like you skip a line everytime you delete one, so you're missing any consecutive cases.  Tim's advice to work from the last row up is spot on.

```
For i = LastRow to 3 Step -1
  If Range("C" & i) = "Result" OR Not InStr(1, Range("Q" & i), "INVOICE") Then
    Rows(i & ":" i).Delete Shift:=x1Up
  End If
Next i
```

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the help! I think I'm going to switch to the autofilter option since it is faster and my datasets are quite bulky.